# Pass in variable amount of arguments python when calling another module

Tags: python, module, python-2.7, argv

So I need to call another module from within a module and I need to pass arguments from a text file. I am going to be reading line by line from a text file and each line of the text file should be an argument for the module I am calling.

Any ideas on how to do this?

-
It is going to be done over the cloud. I am going to take a bunch of parameters from a text file and then pass them over to a server on a cloud that will have a bunch of logic for all of the arguments. I just need to figure out how to make each line of the text file as an argument and then pass all of the lines as arguments to the module in the cloud.

Will call the other module using ssh commands

Comment: I think what you're doing sounds very weird, and you might be going about it very wrong. Can you explain the overall purpose? Why can you not just import the module and call a function, or functions?

Comment: use `subprocess` module

Comment: It is going to be done over the cloud. I am going to take a bunch of parameters from a text file and then pass them over to a server on a cloud that will have a bunch of logic for all of the arguments. I just need to figure out how to make each line of the text file as an argument and then pass all of the lines as arguments to the module in the cloud.

Comment: @user1490083 Do you have direct access to the remote server? Are you sure you can't just write a script, run it on the server, and have that script import the module? The fact that you're using `execfile` would seem to indicate that you are also able to import the file.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, not using execfile, using some ssh commands to access ec2 server and call the module